# Nested object mapping with NPoco 3

Tags: c#, npoco

I'm trying to get a nested mapping running but the nested object is null. Which means in my case `result[0].Location` is null. I'm using NPoco 3.3.0-beta3 together with Postgres.

**Here the code snippet:**

```
var db = new Database(new NpgsqlConnection(configurations["ConnectionStrings:Database"]));

var sql = Sql.Builder
    .Append("SELECT r.*, l.* FROM race r")
    .Append("INNER JOIN location l ON r.location_id = l.id");

using (db.Connection)
{
    db.Connection.Open();
    var result = Db.Fetch<RaceEntity>(sql);
    // result[0].Location == null
}
```

**RaceEntity:**

```
[TableName("race")]
[PrimaryKey("id", AutoIncrement = true)]
public class RaceEntity
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("location_id")]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    [Column("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [ResultColumn]
    public LocationEntity Location { get; set; }
}
```

**LocationEntity**

```
[TableName("location")]
[PrimaryKey("id", AutoIncrement = true)]
public class LocationEntity
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("province")]
    public string Province { get; set; }

    [Column("postal")]
    public string Postal { get; set; }

    [Column("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Column("iso_code")]
    public string IsoCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Race Table**

```
CREATE TABLE "race" (
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
    "location_id" INTEGER REFERENCES "location" (id),
    "date" date NOT NULL
);
```

**Location Table**

```
CREATE TABLE "location" (
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "province" VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "postal" VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "country" VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    "iso_code" VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Comment: Sorry, just had to make a segue comment here: I don't understand how they can put the word poco in the name when the classes are all attribute-adorned... that's not POCO at all! I mean, just look at petapoco and you will understand what I mean...

Comment: @code4life, none of those [Column] mappings are required, nor is the [PrimaryKey] decoration. NPoco would automatically map all those column names correctly with no decorations and it would assume Id as an autoincrementing primary key.  The table names are required, but only because he added the word "Entity" to them.  If he had a folder "Entities" and called the classes Entity.Location and Entity.Race, then those markings wouldn't be needed either.  The [ResultColumn] decoration is because he wants to return them together but is too lazy to make a separate result class from his entity class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove attribute `[ResultColumn]` from `Location` property. `Location` property is not a column in the database and does not therefore require the attribute.

Even if the property was a column in the database, you would require to note the following from [NPoco wiki](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki/Mapping#wiki-body)

> Note: These columns will need to be explicitly specified in the SQL.
>   It will not be included in the auto generated SQL.